# Array.prototype.every on String object

Tags: javascript, arrays

As we all know this is a valid code, which will return false because `test_string` contains an `s`:

```
Array.prototype.every.call('test_string', n => n === 's')
```

My question is: can I implement my object (a generator for example) which I will be able to pass to `Array.prototype.every.call` so it runs predicates on my my objects items. Thank you.

Comment: do you have an example of data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by example data,
I have this generator for example:
```
const number = 1010101

function* generator(number) {
    let n = number
    while (n) yield n % 10 - (n = Math.floor(n / 10)) % 10
}
```

Comment: Function `every` does not take generators as parameters.

Comment: do you really need to use the pattern with `Array.prototype.every.call`? this reqires to have an array, at least an array like object with indices and length property.

Comment: the length I know it is length of `const number = 1010101`, and quantity of indices I also know

Comment: if you have a generator function, why do you need `some`? why not iterate and exit early without having a new array as overhead?

Comment: You are probably right. I should not mix Generators with Arrays. Its just that in Python you can do that easily so I was looking for an analogous thing in js. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an object is fine (but a generator not so much) - it's not very picky so long as the thing you pass has `length`.

[After all, the spec is clear that an ArrayLike object is enough.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.every)

```
> a = {length: 3}
> a[0] = 1
> a[1] = 2
> a[2] = 3
> Array.prototype.every.call(a, p => p < 1)
false
> Array.prototype.every.call(a, p => p <= 3)
true
```

Furthermore, if you need to, you can pass in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for an anonymous object that returns your desired `length` and values for each index from 0 up to `length`:

```
> const o = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      if (prop === "length") return 8;
      const idx = +prop;
      if (!isNaN(idx)) {
        return idx ** 3;
      }
    },
  },
);
> o.length
8
> o[4]
64
```

and as that's an ArrayLike object, it should work with all `Array` methods.

Comment: Thank you, so the bottom line is: do not mix generators with arrays

Answer (score 1):

What `.every` does [is](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.every):

```
2. Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).
3. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
4. Let k be 0.
5. Repeat, while k < len,
  a. Let Pk be ! ToString((k)).
  b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk).
  c. If kPresent is true, then
    i. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
    ii. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(callbackfn, thisArg, « kValue, (k), O »)).
    iii. If testResult is false, return false.
  d. Set k to k + 1.
6. Return true.
```

So, in order to be able to call `.every` on a custom object, what that object needs is

- To have a `.length` property
- To have the values to be checked as ascending integer indicies starting from 0

So, for example, it could be done with the following:

```js
const obj = {
  0: 'foo',
  1: 'bar',
  length: 2,
  someOtherPropertyNotIteratedOver: 555
};

console.log(
  Array.prototype.every.call(
    obj,
    val => typeof val === 'string'
  )
);
```

But a generator function or the iterator it returns doesn't have the required properties. You'll need to expand the iterator yourself into an object on which `.every` can be called - which is trivial with spreading into an array (which then doesn't need the `.prototype` or `.call` either).

```js
function* generator(number) {
  let n = number
  while (n) yield n % 10 - (n = Math.floor(n / 10)) % 10
}

const arr = [...generator(555)];
console.log(arr.every(val => val % 5 === 0));
```

Comment: Thank you. But this defies the whole purpose of the generator. I want it to generate a number on each iteration.

Comment: You mean, you only want, for example, the 2nd number to be generated after the first has been verified by the `.every` callback? Not really possible - as the spec says, you need to have a `.length` up front.

Comment: I know `.length` up front
`, the 2nd number to be generated after the first has been verified by the .every callback` - yes correct

Comment: It doesn't look like you do know the length up front, because you do `while (n) yield n % 10 - (n = Math.floor(n / 10)) % 10` - you only know if the generator continues after a given iteration after *actually finishing the iteration*.

Comment: Yeah, probably should not mix Arrays and Generators. Sad to see that this is not an option in JS.

Comment: It's not that you can't implement the logic you're looking for, you can't just use `Array.prototype.every` for the task.